# Define binary tree function to sum the number of nodes at odd levels

Tags: logic, recursion

I want to define a binary tree function sumOfOdd() that calculates the sum of nodes at odd levels, where the first node starts at 0. For example, the tree T = t(leaf, t(t(leaf, leaf), leaf)) would have the result sumOfOdd(T) = 4 because there are two nodes at level 1 and two at level 3.

I have started by making a function n(t) that calculates the number of nodes in the tree:

- n(leaf) = 1
- n(T(A,B)) = n(A) + n(B)

I am not sure how I should define the rescursive part of sumOfOdd() to only select the odd levels. My base case is:

- sumOfOdd(leaf) = 0

I was thinking of splitting the function into two steps (one branch for even and one for odd) like this:

- sumOfOdd(leaf) = 0
- sumOfOdd(T(T(A,B),T(C,D)) = ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common strategy when defining recursive functions is to slightly generalise the problem. We instead define a function $evensAndOdds : Trees \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, such that given a tree $t$, we have $evensAndOdds(t) = ($number of nodes at even depth, number of nodes at odd depth$)$.

For convenience, we define $flip((x, y)) = (y, x)$, and we define $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)$. We then define $evensAndOdds$ recursively as follows:

Then we recursively define our function by $evensAndOdds(leaf) = (1, 0)$ and
$evensAndOdds(t(a, b)) = (1, 0) + flip(evensAndOdds(a) + evensAndOdds(b))$.

We can then easily use $evensAndOdds$ to define $sumOfOdd$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have defined the function and need help with the structural induction part. Could you help me with this? 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617658/stuctural-induction-for-summing-nodes-at-odd-levels